# Alternative to FiltersAggregator.KeyedFilter in new Java Elasticsearch client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

currently we are in the process of migrating to spring boot 3 ,and since there aren't many migration guides and examples with alternatives to specific queries and aggregations:

**What's the alternative to "FiltersAggregator.KeyedFilter(name, query)"?**
We are setting a AggregationsBuilders.filters() with multiple filters:

here is an example :

```
AggregationBuilder aggregation =
        AggregationBuilders
            .filters("agg",
                new FiltersAggregator.KeyedFilter("men", QueryBuilders.termQuery("gender", "male")),
                new FiltersAggregator.KeyedFilter("women", QueryBuilders.termQuery("gender", "female")));
```

Comment: For everyone who looks for the answer i found this solution , it's working for me : `client.search(sr -> sr.aggregations("agg_name",
        a -> a.filters(f ->
            f.filters(fr -> fr
                .keyed(Map.of(
                    "filter_one", Query.of(q -> q.term(tq -> tq.field("foo").value("bar"))),
                    "filter_two", Query.of(q -> q.term(tq -> tq.field("foo").value("baz")))
                ))))), Void.class);`